# Why i am getting <__NSArrayI 0x600000274e80> Unknown NSArray displayed

Tags: ios, json, swift

As i need to call API and API Expects to receive JSON. So i have created data want to convert into json form As Alamofire required. But when i convert this to Json and print `Jsonobj` before calling `Alamofire` the
 <`NSArrayxxxxx`> displayed.

[image: NSArray Image]

Here I am converting JSON data.

```
let updated_User_No :[String:Any]=["friend_list": self.new_convert_telephone_no,"user_id": user_no];
user_outer_arrary.append(updated_User_No);
user_inner_array=["user_contacts": user_outer_arrary]                    

let bytes = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: user_inner_array, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
var jsonObj = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: bytes, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: Any]

print(bytes)
print(jsonObj)
```

Updated:

```
Alamofire.request(myurl,parameters: jsonObj, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: [])).validate().responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }// result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value
                {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: You say you are using `Alamofire`?  The main GitHub page has two specific examples for POSTing data in json format... Why not just follow those examples?

Comment: `Alamofire` can take a dictionary, it will encode it to `JSON` automatically.

Comment: @DonMag: Sir i have tried everything which i can. but i lost and unable to get valid JSON and proper response.

Comment: @Sulthan: i also think so. but my api did'nt react about this call. so it means there is something wrong. One thing i am sure that API is correct (because android version working fine).

Comment: The API should return at least an error. Please, show us how you are creating the request.

Comment: @Sulthan: Sir check updated. sorry! if i had mistake. bcz i am the new one and i tried everything which i can.

Comment: Well, instead of encoding & decoding JSON, you could pass `user_inner_array` directly to Alamofire as parameters but your way should be working, too. What error are you getting? Did you compare your JSON with the Android JSON?

Comment: @Sulthan: yes i compare it. It's ok. and  i also checked through debugger but the control did'nt enter in the alamofire code block. it executes the main line and then exit and did'nt print anything.

Comment: Didn't you set `startRequestsImmediately` to `false` somewhere? That looks like the request was not even started.

Comment: @Sulthan: No. i even did'nt know this. can u help me out plz.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONSerialization` works through Objective-C and creates Objective-C structures like `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`.  Because you've asked for `.mutableLeaves` the "userContacts" value has to contain mutable values the system maintains them as `NSMutableDictionary` objects stored in an `NSArray` and you are seeing that `NSArray`.

Comment: No, sir, the `I` in `NSArrayI...` stands for ***im**mutable*.

Comment: @Scott: Sir then how can i omit this: i need  only a valid JSON.

Comment: @vadian You're right... it's the leaves that are mutable (duh!).  Answer corrected

Comment: @catalyst You had a JSON data when you got "bytes".   If you want to create a string out of it try `let jsonString = String(data: bytes, encoding: .utf8); print(jsonString)`

Comment: Btw: Both `.mutableContainers` and `.mutableLeaves` are completely useless in Swift. Due to value semantics you get mutability for free using `var`.

Comment: @ScottThompson: Sir i already tried this. but i don't need string because alamofire expects to paramter in [String: Any]

Comment: @vadian: Thanks! but sir how can i solve my problem.

Comment: @catalyst - Sounds like Alamofire wants you to pass it `updated_User_No`

Comment: @ScottThompson: How can i pass Updated_User_No as it does'nt cover "User_Contacts"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a misunderstanding.

You are converting

- A dictionary to JSON data with `data(withJSONObject` and then
- JSON data back to dictionary with `jsonObject(with`.

You need to send **`bytes`** to the server rather than `jsonObj`, however the server does not care about aesthetics so `prettyprinted` is needless.

The second conversion back to dictionary is not needed. Nevertheless the output of `jsonObj` is absolutely correct.

And never pass `.mutableContainers` and `.mutableLeaves` options. They are meaningless in Swift since `var`iables are mutable by default.

Comment: It's true the conversion is not necessary but the code should still work. Alamofire will encode the object by itself into JSON data.

Comment: @Vadian: Sir byte is type Data and alamofire expects [Any] type of parameter. so i convert this. but it always fails.  sir can u help me out more with some piece of code

Comment: I've never used Alamofire in my life but there is certainly an API which takes `Data`. By the way `[Any]` represents an array, you are going to send a dictionary.

Comment: @vadian: ok Sir Thanks!  And what should i use in options

Comment: No writing options, no reading options, just omit both `options` parameters.

Comment: @vadian: thank you sir. but i can't mark this as answer. Because still i am in  trouble. But Thanks!